# snap out of Ubuntu 14.04 .run file

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, snap

I would like to create a snap package `Devolo Cockpit` out of [this .run file](http://www.devolo.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Downloads/Software/software-devolo-cockpit-linux-v4-3-1.run), which was created for Ubuntu 14.04 and doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04.

With a tool called `dpkg-repack` I was able to create out of a Devolo installation on 14.04 three .deb packages:

- `adobeair_2.6.0.19170-devolo1_amd64.deb`
- `devolo-dlan-cockpit_4.3.1-0_amd64.deb`
- `devolo-ia32-libs_1_i386.deb`

Is there a way to setup `snapcraft` in a way to install a .run-file/.deb package(s) – and its dependencies – from Ubuntu 14.04 to create a snap working on Ubuntu 16.04?